# Get the max occurrence of element for every 5 chars in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to get the maximum iteration (15 iterations for ex) of the element for every 5 characters. For example, I have an xml file below:

**INPUT FILE:**

```
<Record>
<AAA>1DFAHSDJFOHR79324325Y49HRFDSHFADSLFJOSDHFDFASNDFAEJRO3U023U4EWR3454433FGSDG46244SDG6409876</AAA>
</Record>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<Record>
<Data>1DFAH</Data>
<Data>SDJFO</Data>
<Data>HR793</Data>
<Data>24325</Data>
<Data>Y49HR</Data>
<Data>FDSHF</Data>
<Data>ADSLF</Data>
<Data>JOSDH</Data>
<Data>FDFAS</Data>
<Data>NDFAE</Data>
<Data>JRO3U</Data>
<Data>023U4</Data>
<Data>EWR34</Data>
<Data>54433</Data>
<Data>FGSDG</Data>
</Record>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="AAA">
<Record>
    <xsl:analyze-string regex=".{{5}}" select=".">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <Data>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Data>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <Data>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Data>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>   
</Record>
</xsl:template>
```

I only need to get the value until 15th iteration of Data and disregard the excess value. How can I do that in my xslt?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="AAA">
        <Record>
            <!-- Assing all in a Variable -->
            <xsl:variable name="DATA">
            <xsl:analyze-string regex=".{{5}}" select=".">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <Data>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </Data>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <Data>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </Data>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>   
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- Copy only first Fifteen Occurances -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="$DATA//Data[position() lt 16]"/>
        </Record>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Record>
   <Data>1DFAH</Data>
   <Data>SDJFO</Data>
   <Data>HR793</Data>
   <Data>24325</Data>
   <Data>Y49HR</Data>
   <Data>FDSHF</Data>
   <Data>ADSLF</Data>
   <Data>JOSDH</Data>
   <Data>FDFAS</Data>
   <Data>NDFAE</Data>
   <Data>JRO3U</Data>
   <Data>023U4</Data>
   <Data>EWR34</Data>
   <Data>54433</Data>
   <Data>FGSDG</Data>
</Record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending your solution further, you can store the output from the `analyze-string` into a variable say `splitArray`.

```
<xsl:variable name="strValue" select="AAA" />
<xsl:variable name="splitArray">
    <xsl:analyze-string regex=".{{5}}" select="$strValue">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <Data><xsl:value-of select="."/></Data>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <Data><xsl:value-of select="."/></Data>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:variable>
```

Add a `for-each` loop on the variable that would extract the first 15 indexes of the stored array

```
<xsl:for-each select="$splitArray/Data[position() &lt; 16]">
    <Data><xsl:value-of select="." /></Data>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The complete XSLT is below for your reference.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="strValue" select="AAA" />
            <xsl:variable name="splitArray">
                <xsl:analyze-string regex=".{{5}}" select="$strValue">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <Data><xsl:value-of select="."/></Data>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                        <Data><xsl:value-of select="."/></Data>
                    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="$splitArray/Data[position() &lt; 16]">
                <Data><xsl:value-of select="." /></Data>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<Record>
   <Data>1DFAH</Data>
   <Data>SDJFO</Data>
   <Data>HR793</Data>
   <Data>24325</Data>
   <Data>Y49HR</Data>
   <Data>FDSHF</Data>
   <Data>ADSLF</Data>
   <Data>JOSDH</Data>
   <Data>FDFAS</Data>
   <Data>NDFAE</Data>
   <Data>JRO3U</Data>
   <Data>023U4</Data>
   <Data>EWR34</Data>
   <Data>54433</Data>
   <Data>FGSDG</Data>
</Record>
```

An alternative option for `analyze-string` is to use the `idiv` feature of XSLT 2.0 for splitting the string into chunks of 5 characters.

```
<xsl:variable name="splitArray">
    <xsl:for-each select="0 to string-length($strValue) idiv 5">
        <Data>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($strValue, . * 5 + 1, 5)" />
        </Data>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you would get non matching strings. As for taking the first 15 matches, `position()` is available, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-matching-substring which explains: "the position of the substring within the sequence of matching and non-matching substrings will be the context position". So you can check it:

```
<xsl:template match="AAA">
    <Record>
        <xsl:analyze-string regex=".{{5}}" select=".">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <xsl:if test="position() le 15">
                <Data>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </Data>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:matching-substring>            
        </xsl:analyze-string>   
    </Record>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQv/2